# Why is the lazy quantifier indeed lazy to the right, but not to the left?

Tags: regex, pcre2

I have this text:

```
start start word word word end
```

and this regex with flag `gm`:

```
start.*?end
```

In my understanding the lazy quantifier `*?` should limit the match to only:

```
start word word word end
```

However it still matches the whole string. However if the string is:

```
start word word word end end
```

Then it works correctly. Why is that?

Comment: Because the engine starts at the left with the first character. The example string starts with `start` and you pattern also starts with `start` so there will be a match from the beginning of the string. Then the engine will try to match as few as possible characters to match `end`. The engine does not skip characters (it moves to the next character if there is no match), so if you don't want to match the first occurrence of `start` or want to match the last consecutive occurrence of `start` you would have to account for that in the pattern.

Comment: @RyszardCzech This closure has already been reversed by moderators once, because it just is not at all the same question. "Why does the lazy quantifier behave in a specific manner?" is a very different question than "How to find the shortest match between two strings".  Moreover, none of the answers on that question answer that.  Please take more care when closing duplicates.

Comment: If you want to match the last `start` and the first `end`, you could use: `start(?!.*start).*?end`.

Comment: This is yet another tempered greedy token problem of course. Is a dupe by all means.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html:

> This is a very important point to understand: a regex engine always returns the leftmost match, even if a “better” match could be found later. When applying a regex to a string, the engine starts at the first character of the string. It tries all possible permutations of the regular expression at the first character. Only if all possibilities have been tried and found to fail, does the engine continue with the second character in the text. Again, it tries all possible permutations of the regex, in exactly the same order. The result is that the regex engine returns the leftmost match.

---

There is a related "leftmost longest" rule, which not all regex engines use.

For example the [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html) definition, under "matched" says:

> The search for a matching sequence starts at the beginning of a string and stops when the first sequence matching the expression is found, where first is defined to mean "begins earliest in the string". If the pattern permits a variable number of matching characters and thus there is more than one such sequence starting at that point, the longest such sequence will be matched. For example: the BRE bb* matches the second to fourth characters of abbbc, and the ERE (wee|week)(knights|night) matches all ten characters of weeknights.

```
$ echo hello | grep -Eo 'hel|hell|hello'
hello
$ echo hello | grep -Eo 'hell|hello|hel'
hello
```

In contrast, Perl tries alternations from left to right and chooses the first that matches:

```
$ echo hello | grep -Po 'hel|hell|hello'
hel
$ echo hello | grep -Po 'hell|hello|hel'
hell
```

Comment: Cần you explain why the third command doesn't result with `hel`?